# Why is "MacBook" an Entity, but not "laptop"?

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, watson

I'm building a Twitterbot to reply to tweets about broken products.

I was trying to use the IBM Watson AlchemyLanguage Entities API to extract products and product types from plain text. Sadly, it doesn't seem to extract any product types, e.g. "laptop", only specific product names, e.g. "MacBook". How can I get it to return "laptop"?

Also, I looked at the XLS sheet of Types and SubTypes linked from the API documentation. The Types are ideal for my purposes, but I can only see the SubTypes in the output. How can I get it to return Types?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that XLS shows that "Product" type doesn't have any subtypes.

How big is the set of products you're trying to monitor? If it's not large you might be able to classify them manually.

Alternatively have you looked at the [Custom Models](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#custom-models)

These allow you to create your own entities which might be domain-specific. It requires [Watson Knowledge Studio](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/supervised-machine-learning).

Comment: I want to extract all man-made objects, so I certainly wouldn't want to classify manually. I don't need subtypes, only types (e.g. Product).

Comment: I will use a Natural Language Classifier once I have create manually classified training data, but I was really hoping AlchemyLanguage would help me create an initial filtered dataset. I guess it can - but only with mentions of "MacBooks" and not "laptops". :(

Comment: so you want it to pick up the entity "laptop" and tell you that it's a product? I think I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I'd like it to extract any kind of Product, e.g. "laptop" or "MacBook".